# Can I enter a Schengen state with a D visa issued by Romania?

Tags: visas, schengen, romania

If Romania joins the Schengen countries, can I fly to France with a Romanian D visa?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. I redacted your personal information on the image of your visa, to protect it. My edits were to help make your question a bit clearer; apologies if I've misunderstood, and you can also use the word *edit* under your question to make any changes you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would depend on the terms of Romania's accession to the Schengen area. Once they are in, their national visa will grant Schengen-wide travel. Some decision must be made for existing visa.